# Editing Package name of a guided rule in RED HAT BRMS

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, redhat-brms

I am trying to edit the package of guided rule in Red Hat BRMS,is there any way I can do it through the UI.

Reason for me to ask for it is, I want to restructure the package structure of my project. When I rename my packages, the rules inside the package still reflect the old package name instead of new package structure.

Answer (score 0):

On the cog icon, select Repository View.  This displays icons next to each folder/package segment.  The rename operation exists as one of the icons.

Comment: But this doesn't change the package declaration for  the assets in that package

Comment: Yeah, nice bug.

Answer (score 0):

Above approach will rename the package,it will not move the assets accross different package. Workbench didnt provide option to change asset package. To change asset package you have to clone repository into filesystem/IDE make the required changes and push it back to server.